# How to center button in Quadrant in size classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, size-classes

I have Storyboard of any any size. i want to center first,second, third, fourth button in each Quadrant. how to set constraints? with respect to UILable.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take 4 view for 4 button

(right top) View 1 - Trailing = 0 and Top = 0 to superview,horizontal space = 0 to  view 2 and vertical space = 0 to view 4

(left top) View 2 - Leading = 0 and top = 0 to superView

(left bottom) View 3 - leading = 0 and bottom = 0 to superview,horizontal space = 0 to view 4 and vertical space = 0 to view 2

(right bottom) View 4 - Trailing = 0 and Bottom = 0 to superview

Equal height and width for all view

put each button in each view with horizontal and vertical centre with superview

**Second Option :** 
set every button horizontal and vertical center of view and set multiplier as below

for button 1 (right-Top)

```
center x: multiplier = 1.5
center y: multiplier = 0.5
```

for button 2 (Left-Top)

```
center x: multiplier = 0.5
center y: multiplier = 0.5
```

for button 3 (Left-Bottom)

```
center x: multiplier = 0.5
center y: multiplier = 1.5
```

for button 4 (right-Bottom)

```
center x: multiplier = 1.5
center y: multiplier = 1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use centre horizontally / vertically.  Then all you also need is to set width and height of each.

[image]

Comment: (if you also need constraints for the 4 quadrants, thats more work .. )

Comment: this will put 4 button at center of screen.

Comment: you didnt say that your quadrants also need setting up .. :(

Answer (score 0):

Apply aspect ratio on all buttons and add vertical center and horzontol centre constraint only.

[image]"
 [image]"

Answer (score 0):

Take 4 views for each quadrant.

[image]

Constrain views as.
[image] 
[image]

Add button as subview of view. Add vertical as well as horizontal constrain to button w.r.t to its superView .

[image]

Repeat for all 3 views. 
Finally your constrains shud look like

[image]

Hope it helps. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
for first button:
button.centerX = 1.5*centerX;
button.centerY = 0.5*centerY;

for second button:
button.centerX = 0.5*centerX;
button.centerY = 0.5*centerY;

for third button:
button.centerX = 0.5*centerX;
button.centerY = 1.5*centerY;

for fourth button:
button.centerX = 1.5*centerX;
button.centerY = 1.5*centerY;
```

and add constraints for height and width for buttons and done.

Comment: @AvijitNagare when you create center horizontally constraint it will be created as above in the answer. Change the multiplier as i write